# How do I compare two strings together to see if one is greater than the other(alphabetically)? c#

Tags: c#

How do I compare two strings together to see if one is greater than the other(alphabetically)? for example if I were to compare b and a, a would be greater than b because it comes first in the alphabet.

This is what I am trying to compare:

```
if (StringArray[lower] <= StringArray[middle])
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc165449.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`String.Compare`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkcaxw5y%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

```
var control = string.Compare("a", "b") > 0;
```

This will return `false` because `b` is greater than `a`, if you want to reverse it then change it like this:

```
var control = string.Compare("a", "b") < 0;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I tired String.Compare but it didn't work. When I added the < 0 at the end it did!

Comment: @Maattt Also be mindful that the string.Compare by default is case sensitive.  There is an additional parameter to change this behavior

Answer (score 1):

please check :

```
  {
    string a = "a"; // 1
    string b = "b"; // 2

    int c = string.Compare(a, b);
    Console.WriteLine(c);

    c = string.CompareOrdinal(b, a);
    Console.WriteLine(c);

    c = a.CompareTo(b);
    Console.WriteLine(c);

    c = b.CompareTo(a);
    Console.WriteLine(c);
    }
```

Output

```
-1       (This means a is smaller than b)
 1        (This means b is smaller than a)
-1
 1
```